# update xml using linq in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, updates

I am a .net beginner.

I am trying to update my [**xml file**](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ) using linq.

I got stuck at the very first point of it i.e i cant grab the value from xml file using linq.

These are the controls I am using in my code:

```
cbBrandName -- combobox
cbProduct   -- combobox
txtQuantity -- TextBox
```

I am trying the below code:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
string quantity = doc.Descendants("quantity")
                  .Select(y => y.Element("quantity").Value.Equals(txtQuantity.Text))
/*red scribbles to 'Element' in 'where'*/ 
                  .Where(x => x.Element("productname").Value.Equals(cbProduct.Text) &&
                  x.Element("brandname").Value.Equals(cbBrandName.Text)).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(quantity.ToString());
```

here I am trying to store the "quantity" value in `quantity` string so that i can manipulate it later and then again update to my xml file.

when I make `.select` as comment it isn't showing any errors but when i run it, instead of text it is showing some `system.linq.Enumerable + .....` in the MessageBox.

EDIT:

[image]

when i give `.toString()` at the end it. It is showing error -- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when i run it.

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ERROR : Error 1 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Just show us xml format and result what you want.

Comment: I have given the link to xml format in my question. Please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/App_Data/XMLFile.xml");
        string quantity = doc.Descendants("items")
        .Select(y => y.Element("quantity").Value)
        .Where(x => x.Element("productname").Value.Equals(cbProduct.text) && x.Element("brandname").Value.Equals(cbBrandName.text))
        .Single().Element("quantity").Value;
```

**THIS WORKS**

**UPDATING XML VALUE**

```
 doc.Descendants("items")
    .Where(x => x.Element("productname").Value.Equals(cbProduct.Text) && x.Element("brandname").Value.Equals(cbBrandName.Text))
    .Single().Element("quantity").SetValue(quantity);
        doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/App_Data/XMLFile.xml");
```

Comment: oh  of course. you are selecting bool. @Mr_Green See the update in a minute.

Comment: .Single().Value;

if it is not what you want just tell me what you want to select in quantity

Comment: i want to select text present in the `quantity` tag of xml

Comment: Please check the link in my question or check this [xml file](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ)

Comment: check your code once.. it has some errors like where is repeating instead of select. and use combobox names instead of tag names :)

Comment: yes it's  hard coded you can replace those values by textBox.Text etc

Comment: now i need to load the string value into the same xml. can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. you were repeating `where` in your code which i edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Its returning the text that you see because it's returning a collection of elements, not a single element. If you want just one element you can try to use the

```
YourCollection.FirstOrDefault()
```

method for example.

In your case:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
var quantity = doc.Descendants("quantity")
              .Select(y => y.Element("quantity").Value.Equals(txtQuantity.Text))
/*red scribbles to 'Element' in 'where'*/ 
              .Where(x => x.Element("productname").Value.Equals(cbProduct.Text) &&
              x.Element("brandname").Value.Equals(cbBrandName.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
MessageBox.Show(quantity.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried this but still it is showing red scribbles to 'Element' in 'where'.

Comment: try using the where statement before the select statement.

Comment: It is showing red scribbles to firstOrDefault() with same error as i shown in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get one element from collection because `linq` returns collection of "filtered" elements (even if it contains only one element). To do that you've choices: `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Last()`, `LastOrDefault()`, `Single()`, SingleOrDefault()`.

The difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` is that first one will throw `ArgumentNullException` if sequence contains no element, second one will return default value of collection element (`null` for string)

In your example:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
string quantity = doc.Descendants("quantity")
                  .Select(y => y.Element("quantity").Value.Equals(txtQuantity.Text))
/*red scribbles to 'Element' in 'where'*/ 
                  .Where(x => x.Element("productname").Value.Equals(cbProduct.Text) &&
                  x.Element("brandname").Value.Equals(cbBrandName.Text))
                  .First();
MessageBox.Show(quantity.ToString());
```

Comment: @Mr_Green Use `Where` before `Select`.

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh, Forgive me the error should be that in `Select` you make `IEnumerable<bool>`. And bool can't be implicitly converted to string. So in `select` you need to remove `Equalst(txtQuantity.Text)`. And remove `.ToArray` too.

Comment: ahh yes. I am such a noob. Now it is showing runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." pointing to where clause. any idea why so?